# Cloudbees using WebapplicationInitializer says No WebApplicationContext found

Tags: spring, cloudbees, servlet-3.0

Using Spring 3.2, JSF 2.1, JBoss AS7.1 at home and Cloudbees uses JBoass AS7.0.1. I am also using Servlet 3.0 and a WebApplicationInitializer(A spring class).(I think the root of the problem is the WebApplicationInitializer is not being loaded, Maybe it's being loaded too late? early?) I do have a web.xml and I only get this message on views that should be bringing up JSF pages, if I type in nonsense like /xlksdf.xhtml I get a different unrelated error message.

To start off this only happens on cloudbees when I deploy my application to JBoss AS7.1 at home it runs correctly.

When I war up my application and deploy to cloudbees I get this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    org.springframework.web.jsf.FacesContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(FacesContextUtils.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver.getWebApplicationContext(SpringBeanFacesELResolver.java:91)
    org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver.getBeanFactory(SpringBeanFacesELResolver.java:79)
```

Cloudbees show the server at the bottom of the error screen

```
JBoss Web/7.0.1.Final
```

At home I've been able to re-create this problem simply by deleting my class that implements WebApplicationInitializer. That leads me to believe that the most likely reason I'm getting this on cloudbees is because WebApplicationInitializer is not being recognized? perhaps it's running in Servlet 2.5 mode? I am running JBoss as is verified by the error message which is servlet 3.0. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to try running your app on same JBoss 7.0.1, to ensure this isn't a container issue.

Then, you should deploy a very basic servlet 3.0 web application with just a [ServletContainerInitializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) to confirm you assumption